# Apache server not able to run php script containing python code

Tags: php, python, apache

This is how my python code looks like:

[root@localhost html]# vi brow1.php

```
<?php
echo exec("whoami");
echo exec("ls -l brow1.php") . "<br>";
$command = escapeshellcmd('/usr/temp_rohit.py');
shell_exec($command);
?>
```

I want to call python script from this php. 
If i run the php script then it executes the python code but when run from the browser it does not execute the python script.

python script has all the required execute permission.

The output on the web browser is:

apache
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 219 Nov 26 23:03 brow1.php
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 115 Nov 26 22:38 /usr/temp_rohit.py

I am stuck at this point, Please help!

Comment: What is the first line of your python script ? Plus, you should fetch the output of `shell_exec()` and echo it.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/python2.6

import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen("sudo mkdir /rohit",stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)

Comment: remove the part before the import and try creating a new first line with `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: Tried that, #!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen("sudo mkdir /don",stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True) this is how my code now looks like, but not working even now. Could this be user issue? Since apache runs with 'apache' user

Comment: Check the permissions of `/usr` and make sure the execute bit is set for all users. Make sure safe mode is turned off in your php.ini. Depending on your OS, apache and the php cli may use different ini files.

Comment: drwxr-xr-x. 13 root root 4096 Nov 26 23:14 /usr/ I am using Centos

Comment: php script when run direcly is run with user 'root' and with apache server it is run with 'apache' user. Could this be a problem??

Comment: ; Safe Mode
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode
safe_mode = Off
safe mode is already off at /etc/php.ini

Comment: Yes, the user it's running as, is probably the issue. Have you tried running the python program as the apache user? `sudo -u apache /usr/temp_rohit.py` What's the output of `getenforce` in your shell?

Comment: [root@localhost /]# getenforce
Enforcing
[root@localhost /]# sudo -u apache /rohit/temp_rohit.py
Executing the python command:
[root@localhost /]# mkdir: cannot create directory `/don': Permission denied
this is how it looks, when i change the user to root it lets me run the python script successfully

Comment: Could you please tell me how do make 'apache' run the command e.g mkdir

Comment: You should not be creating directories under `/` as apache. You should create a subdirectory, at least. `mkdir /apache`, `chown apache:apache /apache`. This will give apache read and write access to the directory `/apache`. You can then either move the script there, or `chdir` in your script to `/apache`. Also, you should be using the `os` functions instead of `subprocess`. https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html

Comment: thanks for the reply, now I am able to execute sudo -u apache /apache/temp_rohit.py successfully, also when i run php /var/www/html/brow1.php it works, but with browser its still not working,the thing is it even does not print the 'print' function in the python code, completely stuck, please help.

Comment: any apache/php server version mismatch?btw, on browser it shows the php specific output, just when i try to call the python script it doesnt echoes anything on the browser